# How to make a table in android have a picture and 2 textviews?

Tags: java, android

This my first question so please guide me if I'm asking in the wrong way.I want to use a table to show number of characters in my game who has a picture, Title and a brief description. Upon clicking a character the user will be transferred into another view where he can see more detailed information about the character.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you any code to show us?  (You are unlikely to get people to help you unless you try first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed as your layout may contain `TextView(Title)` in First Row of `Table` with `ImageView(Your Picture)` and `TextView(Brief Description)`. You can use `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight` as per the requirement of your `TableRow`

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
 >

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <TextView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="Title"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >
        <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="drawable/...png"
            />
       <TextView 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Brief Description"
            />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```